# How do I count discontinued dates in PowerBI?

Tags: date, count, powerbi, dax

**I want to count the discontinued dates per ID with filter "FilterByValue" by 1.**

What I mean by discontinued dates.

- 04.01.2021
- 05.01.2021
- 06.01.2021
- **08.01.2021**

**07.01.2021** date would be missing to be a continued date  when a day between dates is missing its **discontinued**.

Dates have also to be **distinct** and within the **last 90 Days**.

**RowID** is just for explanation purposes.

| RowID | ID | FilterByValue | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Monday, 4. January 2021 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | Tuesday, 5. January 2021 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | Tuesday, 5. January 2021 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | Wednesday, 6. January 2021 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | Monday, 11. January 2021 |
| 6 | 1 | 99 | Friday, 8. January 2021 |
| 7 | 2 | 1 | Tuesday, 9. February 2021 |
| 8 | 2 | 1 | Wednesday, 10. February 2021 |
| 9 | 2 | 1 | Thursday, 11. March 2021 |
| 10 | 2 | 1 | Friday, 12. March 2021 |
| 11 | 2 | 1 | Monday, 15. March 2021 |
| 12 | 2 | 1 | Tuesday, 16. March 2021 |
| 13 | 2 | 99 | Sunday, 14. March 2021 |
| 14 | 2 | 1 | Wednesday, 14. April 2021 |

What I want to achieve:

| RowID | ID | CountDiscontinuedDates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 |

What I tried, I think is a bad/ not helping approach:

```
discontinuesDates = COUNTAX(FILTER(TableName, [ID]=1 && TableName[Date] > (TODAY()-90) && OR (DATEADD( TableName[Date] = (TableName[Datum],1,DAY), DATEADD( TableName[Date] = (TableName[Datum],-1,DAY) ) && TableName[ID] = EARLIER(TableName[ID]) && TableName[Date] = TableName[Date] ), TableName[ID])
```

```
discontinuesDates = CALCULATE(COUNT(TableName[ID]), FILTER(TableName, TableName[FilterByValue]=34 && TableName[ID] = EARLIER( TableName[ID]) && DATEADD( TableName[Date],1,DAY) <> EARLIER( TableName[Date])) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

Assuming that FilterByValue is available to use:

```
_Foo = 
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( DiscontinuedDatesData[Date] ),
    FILTER (
        DiscontinuedDatesData,
        'DiscontinuedDatesData'[Date] >= CALCULATE (MIN ( 'DiscontinuedDatesData'[DATE] ), 'DiscontinuedDatesData', DiscontinuedDatesData[FilterByValue] = 99)
        && 'DiscontinuedDatesData'[Date] >= TODAY() - 90
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late response, actually never solved it with PowerBi.
I solved it with python now.